# Как преобразовать полученный GET запрос

Tags: swift, http, get, alamofire

При GET запросе с сервера я получаю такой ответ:

```
   "disclaimer": "Usage subject to terms: https://openexchangerates.org/terms",
  "license": "https://openexchangerates.org/license",
  "timestamp": 1665594000,
  "base": "USD",
"rates": {
    "AED": 3.67295,
    "AFN": 85.5,
    "ALL": 119.95,
}
```

Хочу его подстроить под себя, привести его к такому виду:

```
"disclaimer": "Usage subject to terms: https://openexchangerates.org/terms",
  "license": "https://openexchangerates.org/license",
  "timestamp": 1665594000,
  "base": "USD",
  "rates": [
    {
        "key":  "AED"
        "value": 3.76295
    },
    {
        "key":  "AFN"
        "value": 85.5
    },
    {
        "key":  "ALL"
        "value": 119.95
    }
  ]
```

Как мне это сделать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если вы хотите как-то изменить структуру получаемых данных, то можно это сделать с помощью ручной реализации `init(from decoder: Decoder)`

```
struct Response: Decodable {
    
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case disclaimer
        case license
        case timestamp
        case base
        case rates
    }
    
    var disclaimer: String
    var license: String
    var timestamp: Int
    var base: String
    var rates: [Rate]
    
    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        disclaimer = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .disclaimer)
        license = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .license)
        timestamp = try container.decode(Int.self, forKey: .timestamp)
        base = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .base)
        // ручное преобразование данных
        let ratesDictionary = try container.decode([String : Double].self, forKey: .rates)
        rates = ratesDictionary.map { key, value in Rate(key: key, value: value) }
    }
}

struct Rate: Decodable {
    var key: String
    var value: Double
}
```